# Homework: Which of these sets are closed under scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

One of the questions in an assignment I'm working on is as follows:

> Which of the following sets in $\mathbb{R}^4$ are closed under the usual operation in $\mathbb{R}^4$ of multiplication by scalars?
>
> $S=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4~|~ab=0\text{ and }d=0\}$
>
> $T=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4~|~a+b=1\text{ and }c=d\}$
>
> $U=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4~|~b\ge 0\text{ and }c\le 0\}$
>
> $V=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4~|~a+b-c+2d=0\}$

What I've found so far is that, if tested using *only* scalar multiplication, the first three  sets are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4$. I'm a bit skeptical; this answer seems to easy. For each set, I performed this kind of test:

For S:

$\forall~r\in\mathbb{R}: ra, rb,rc,rd\in\mathbb{R}^4$

$\therefore$ S is a closed set under scalar multiplication.

Am I performing this test wrong? Am I misinterpreting the results? Or is this correct, and this has just been a trivially simple question?

Comment: Not only must these vectors be in $\mathbb R^4$ when multiplied by scalars, they must also satisfy the properties required to be in the set.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, in the case of $U$, multiplication by a negative scalar may cause b and c to exit their restrictions, right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is test it like this: Multiply by a scalar. Do you get a vector with the properties of you initial set?

For instance let $(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{R}^4$ be an element of $S$. Multiply by a scalar and you get: $(ra,rb,rc,rd)$. Now ask "Does this vector live in $S$?". How do you check that? We check, that the first two coordinates multiply to $0$, and that the last coordinate is $0$. The answer here is yes, $(ra)(rb)=r^2(ab)=r^2(0)=0$ since $ab=0$, and $rd=0$ since $d=0$.

Can you do the other ones?